# CSS não carrega de acordo com a rota no laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel, route, rotas

Possuo um arquivo blade no qual ele é o meu layout base (que vai ser carregado em todas as páginas). Mas de acordo que eu coloca a rota, o css dessa página não carrega. Ex.:

se a minha rota for assim:

```
Route::get('/novo', 'UserController@novo');
```

O css carrega, mas se eu colocar assim:

```
Route::get('/users/novo', 'UserController@novo');
```

O meu css não carrega!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido. é somente alterar o href da tag link.

Antes:

```
<link href="/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">nsira o código aqui
```

Correção:

```
<link href="{{URL::asset('/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```